# Sort Users by Number of Followers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a simple follower system in my application and I can get the number of any user's followers by running `User.followers.count`. However, when I try to sort all users by the number of followers they each have with `@orderedUsers = User.all.order("followers.count DESC")` it returns the error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: followers.count". Obviously, this is because there is no such column. Is there a way to work around this to do what I wish to achieve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
@ordered_users = User.all.sort{|a,b| a.followers.count <=> b.followers.count}
```

For the reverse order, you can do:

```
@ordered_users = User.all.sort{|a,b| b.followers.count <=> a.followers.count}
```

Or, `.reverse`, as you say in the comments.

**EDIT**: @Alex Quach left a good alternative in a different post. I've modified it for where it will not include the current user in the list, which may be helpful:

`User.all.where('id != ?', current_user.id).sort_by { |u| -u.followers.count }`

Comment: Thanks a ton! All I had to do was add `.reverse` to the end of it to make it appear in descending order. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Collin You can swap the counts to reverse the sort. No need to reverse the sorted array.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs - good point, thanks. Also, don't know if this is possible or not within a single line of code, but how would I go about getting the top 100 in that list, and then choosing 5 at random from within that list? I've looked around and am completely lost as to if that can be accomplished or not.

Comment: @Collin - May I suggest you post a new question?

Comment: @Collin It seems like most of us have missed the fact that this is the result of a SQL query. You shouldn't sort the result of an SQL query in Ruby: you should include the sort criteria in the query as in Deekshith's answer.

Comment: @jvillian - Good suggestion. I started a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041862/randomize-selections-in-a-list-of-100

Answer (score 3):

This code should work (assuming the DB table names are users and followers):

```
User.joins(:followers).order("count(followers.user_id) desc")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly consider using a counter cache on the User model, to hold the count of followers.

This would give a very small performance impact on adding or removing followers, and greatly increase performance when performing sorts:

```
User.order(followers_count: :desc)
```

This would be particularly noticeable if you wanted the top-n users by follower count, or finding users with no followers.