# Randomize Selections in a List of 100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a follow-up to this last question I asked: [Sort Users by Number of Followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023758/sort-users-by-number-of-followers/45027209). That code is:

`@ordered_users = User.all.sort{|a,b| b.followers.count <=> a.followers.count}`

What I hope to accomplish is take the ordered users and get the top 100 of those and *then* randomly choose 5 out of that 100. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use `#sample` to grab randomly from the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```rb
users_in_descending_order_of_followers = User.all.sort_by { |u| -u.followers.count }
sample_of_top = users_in_descending_order_of_followers.take(100).sample(5)
```

You can use `sort_by` which can be easier to use than `sort`, and combine `take` and `sample` to get the top 100 users and sample 5 of those users.

Comment: Don't know why this didn't occur to me or why I couldn't find it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: With `n` users, this is `n+1` SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

`User.all.sort` can "potentially" pose some problems in the long-run, depending on the number of total users, and the availability of resources particularly computer memory, not to mention it would be a lot slower because you're calling 2x `.followers.count` inside the `sort` block, which essentially calls 2xN times more DB query; N being the number of users. This is because `User.all.sort` will immediately execute the `User.all` query, thereby fetching all `User` records into memory, as opposed to your usual `User.all`, which is lazy loaded, until you (for example use `.each`, or better yet `.find_each` somewhere down the line)

I suggest something like below (I extended Deekshith's answer referring to your link to the other question):

```
User.joins(:followers).order('count(followers.user_id) desc').limit(100).sample(5)
```

- `.joins`, `.order`, and `.limit` above will all extend the SQL string query into one string, then executes that SQL string, and finally run `.sample(5)` (not a SQL anymore!, but is already just a plain ruby method at this point), finally yielding the result that you needed.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but your above example did not work. I will tweak it as needed and see if I can produce the intended result.

Comment: That code assumes that the `:followers` relationship is the same table name which should be `followers`, and that the foreign key is `user_id`

Comment: If this is already your schema, but still didn't work, I'll have to test this later.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly consider using a counter cache on the User model, to hold the count of followers.

This would give a very small performance impact on adding or removing followers, and greatly increase performance when performing sorts:

```
User.order(followers_count: :desc)
```

This would be particularly noticeable if you wanted the top-n users by follower count, or finding users with no followers.

```
User.order(followers_count: :desc).limit(100).sample(5)
```

This method will out-perform others using `count(*)`. Add an index on `followers_count` for best effect.